# If $\Pr\{Y<t \mid X\} < f(t)$, where $f(t)$ doesn't depend on $X$, then unconditionally, $\Pr\{Y<t\} < f(t)$, right?

Tags: probability

($t \in R$ and $f(t) \in [0,1]$). I want to keep $X$ and $Y$ general, but if it is easier, you can assume that they are continuous rv's (or even, Normal rv's), and say, $f(t) = \exp(-t^2)$.

I think it is intuitively right, since $\Pr\{Y<t \mid X\} < f(t)$ for any value of $X$, then I can safely drop the conditioning and get $Pr\{Y<t\} < f(t)$.
But is it theoretically correct, or can you give a counter-example?

If it is correct, can we use this kind of reasoning to prove that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, i.e. if $\Pr\{Y<t \mid X\} < f(t)$, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Thanks!

Comment: In $P(Y < t | X) < f(t)$, what are the conditions on $X$ and $Y$? In general this is totally false: take $X = Y$ and $f(t) = 1$, and suppose $X$ can take a value bigger than $1$ w.p. $>0$.

Comment: I just edited my question to assume that X and Y are normal. Back to your answer, suppose X=Y, then consider f(t)=1 or t=1, or both? And why is it totally false?

Comment: If $\Bbb{P}(Y < t \mid X) < f(t)$ a.s. in $\Bbb{P}$, then taking expectation to both sides gives $\Bbb{P}(Y < t) < f(t)$.